Is it possible to cut a 10cm (4 inches) basil stem and regrow its roots for replanting?
I have a basil plant that got really distressed by repotting it and all the leaves from the lower parts of the stem fell off and the stem itself turned brown. RN its trying to escape its new pot as best as it can.

I'd like to reign it in and cut the tops of the 4 main branches it has from where the green starts, regrow the roots in a jar of water and then plant it back. I know that this is how one can multiply a basil plant, by cutting under each node but I just want to keep the branches whole. The thing is, I don't know if the stems would survive the process as it may be hard to pull enough water for the whole length of it.
So question is, would the basil survive if I do this?

Given the apparently dim, windowless location, I'd say that this plant that loves full sun is distressed by a lack of light, more than anything else.

That is the normally advised way to do it.  4 inches is not too long, stems are good at drawing water.  Cut the basil right below a node, remove the leaves from the bottom section of the stem, and set it in refreshed water until roots appear.


 (image source) 
I don't know if it will survive, but this will give it a good chance.

It wasn't your question, but I do wonder if the plant is escaping its pot to look for more sunlight.  Is it getting enough light?

Yes.. the problem is that currently my country gets around 3 hours of sunlight per day, if its not cloudy, which it usually is.

So you either save some basil seeds for spring, or you turn on some artificial lights suitable for plants. Which need not be those marketed specifically for plants, but are considerably brighter than that pink salt lamp.
